# Moving a div when hovering an a-tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the properties of class "divToMove" while hovering a-tag `someBtn`?

I have tried this, but it is not working...

```
#someBtn:hover .divToMove {
     /* properties... */
}


<div class="menu-slider">
 <a id="someBtn" href=""></a>
 <div class="divToMove"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `#someBtn:hover + .divToMove` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that as well :/ @Akshay

Comment: Then you did something wrong https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/oyxxa17b/

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried it once more and now it worked! Thanks a lot! @Akshay

Answer (score 2):

Target the next sibling of the link. This should work fine:

```
#someBtn:hover + .divToMove{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```css
.divToMove {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#someBtn:hover + .divToMove {
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-slider">
 <a id="someBtn" href="">Hover over me</a>
 <div class="divToMove">Move me</div>
</div>
```